# Laravel from Livewire to Fotify

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How do you pass data from livewire to fortify? For example, I would like to do a registration in livewire and send those information to fortify. The fortify documentation is not covering everything. I appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I haven't found a solution yet to this one. Do you have one?

Comment: The answer seems to be covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407732/how-to-send-data-colected-with-laravel-livewire-to-fortify